# Zip files into multiple zip files with maximum length

Tags: bash, shell, zip, batch-processing, zsh

I have a directory with thousands of files. These files are about ten to a hundred Kb each. Now I'm looking for a way to ZIP these files into ZIP archives. However there are some constraints.

- The ZIP archives have a maximum size of a 4 MB each.
- The archives need to be individually extractable, splitting and contacting a big ZIP file is therefore not an option.
- I'm bound to ZIP. TAR, RAR, DAR, etc is not an option. :(

Most of the files are already in some compressed format (e.g. images). It is therefore ok to assume that the zip file is about the size of the sum of its extracted content.

I was thinking in the direction of using Bash/ZSH to loop over the files while keeping an array of file names and sum of file size. As soon as the maximum total file size is exceeded I would like to zip the files in the filename array and continue with a fresh array and filesize counter.

Comment: As an alternative, have you thought of creating one zip file (if this is possible) and using [zipsplit](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zipsplit.html) to split into smaller zipfiles?

Comment: @Component10 Ow, wow. That does exactly what I want. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can add files to the archive and test its size at each iteration. Then, if the size is above the limit, remove the last file from the archive and create a fresh one.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=1
for file in *;
do
  zip "archive$count.zip" "$file"
  archivesize=$(wc -c < "$file")
  if (( archivesize>2*1024*1024  )); then
    zip -d "archive$count.zip" "$file"
    ((count++))
    zip "archive$count.zip" "$file"
  fi
done
```